# SBT JDKpackager error invoking method

Tags: java-8, sbt, packaging, sbt-native-packager

### Summary

I am having difficulty running and debugging a CLI application built with SBT Native Packager - browsing similar questions yielded little insight as they are either referring directly to JDK packager (via JavaFX) or are simply incomplete/unanswered. Running the application throws an error message that is hard to reason about and/or track down the root cause of (no logs).

### Stack

- JDK 8u60
- SBT 0.13.9
- sbt-native-packager 1.0.6
- Inno Setup 5.5.8

The intention is to build Windows installation package - which seems correctly built (I am able to install it to another machine).

### Error details

After installing the packaged app, one of two happens:

- running the app without any command parameters does nothing (no errors printed to console, dead silent)
- running the app with a parameter `--help` (which hits a code path in main method that prints out the help file) yields "Error invoking method" followed with "Failed to launch JVM" errors. I could not find any error logs or further precise hints. The application's bootstrap is practically a single class (containing `main()`) contained in its own SBT module, which in turn produces its own JAR.

### Investigation

In absence of any idea where to start I started to investigate this with following results:

- there are two bootstrap JARs produced, let's call them `bootstrap.jar` and `bootstrap-launcher.jar`

  - both contain `MANIFEST.MF` with the `Main-Class` element correctly populated
  - the former doesn't contain `Class-Path` element but contains elements like `Implementation-Title` and so on. It contains the compiled bootstrap class at the expected package. The `Main-Class` in its manifest file points to that package.
  - the latter is directly opposite the former: its manifest file contains `Class-Path` and `Main-Class` elements, nothing else. Additionally, it doesn't contain any compiled code whatsoever

### Experiments

I performed the following experiments with bootstrap JARs:

- deleting `bootstrap.jar` or `bootstrap-launcher.jar`
- renaming and overwriting `bootstrap-launcher.jar` -> `bootstrap.jar`
- renaming and overwriting `bootstrap.jar` -> `bootstrap-launcher.jar`
- manually adding `Class-Path` entries from `bootstrap.jar` manifest file to `bootstrap-launcher.jar`'s manifest file (a.k.a. desperation mode)
- end result of these experiments is always the same: 'Class com...Bootstrap not found' exception thrown in a GUI window; no further explanations or stacktraces

At this point in time I have no other ideas so I would appreciate any insight.

Additionally, I see library dependencies correctly materialized in `lib` directory, so at least I surmise this is working correctly.

### `build.sbt`

Lastly, for completion, I am attaching my current `build.sbt` file. The reason it's structured as is, is because I used to use `sbt-assembly` to produce a fat JAR - it worked quite nicely but new packaging was requested. Tracing down the issue, I removed all traces of `sbt-assembly` from build, except from `plugins.sbt` (simply as convenience of easier fallback, should the need arise).

```
lazy val root: Project = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(common, commonTest, core, bootstrapCli)

lazy val common: Project = (project in file("common"))
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies := ...

lazy val commonTest: Project = (project in file("commonTest"))
  .dependsOn(common % "compile -> test")
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies := ...
  )

lazy val core: Project = (project in file ("core"))
  .dependsOn(common, commonTest % "test -> test")
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies := ...,
    javacOptions in (Compile, compile) ++= Seq("-parameters"),
    javacOptions in doc ++= Seq.empty,
  )

lazy val bootstrapCli: Project = (project in file("bootstrapCli"))
  .dependsOn(core % "compile -> compile;test -> test")
  .enablePlugins(JDKPackagerPlugin)
  .settings(
    jdkPackagerType := "exe",
    mainClass in Compile := Some("com._3esi.load.bootstrap.cli.Bootstrap")
  )
```

Again, I'd greatly appreciate any insight.

Comment: Have you tried running your application directly with the startscript scripts provided by sbt-native-packager? The [bootstrap-launcher.jar](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/topics/longclasspath.html#generate-a-launcher-jar) is a way to deal with long classpaths.

Comment: Originating issue can be found [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/727). @Muki - I've summarized my findings on the link....but am running out of ideas on where to look. Any thoughts?

Comment: Usually a launch problem is associated with some classpath/dependency issue. Getting console output on windows is a major hassle, but can be done if you launch the program from the command line and redirect output to a file. See what happens if you do `myprog.exe > output.txt`. I've got about 6 mutli-module apps using this plugin without issue, so I'm sure it's something small yet hidden.

Comment: PS: I have not ever used the plugin with `sbt-assembly`, so there may be some interference there, particularly if there's a dependency collision or eviction. I suggest running [`sbt-dependency-graph`](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) (task `dependencyBrowseGraph`) to visualize where version collisions might be. I'd suggest not using `sbt-assembly` when deploying as a bundle.

Comment: PSS: One way to speed up debugging is to run `ant` directly against the `build.xml` file that's generated in `target/jdkpackager` after `jdkPackager:packageBin` is run once. It will list the classpath as it will be defined in the launcher. You can tweak it manually if that helps. Again, my suspicion is that `sbt-assembly` is causing problems.

Comment: @SimeonFitch - thanks for the hints. Just to be clear: I am not using `sbt-assembly` together with `sbt-native-packager`; I used to use it, but I commented out everything except the definition in `plugins.sbt`. Eventually, I removed it completely and it didn't help. The problem with console output is probably due to the fact `javapackager` is relying on pre-existing JavaFX packaging routines which are ultimately linked as a "Windows non-console application" - which disables console altogether unless, as you say, you redirect. Still,I am no closer to solution here. This can't be this difficult.

Comment: Can you post a gist with the output from redirecting to a file? It works with non-console windows apps (output is attached to file before detached from launching process).

Comment: I'll do that - in the interest of progress and backed against a corner, I had to double back and re-think my strategy. However, I did stash my changes on an ancillary branch, so as soon as I finish with my current approach. In a nutshell, I took the middle man out (the `sbt-native-packager`), assembled everything into a fat jar with `sbt-assembly` and then invoked the appropriate `javapacker` incantation directly as a separate Task after assembly. I'll wrap this up and, time permitting, jump back and give you more information. I am very curious what went wrong and where.

Comment: @quantum I'd be happy to help debug further if you can create a stand-alone example that reproduces the issue.